# PHP timestamp different in total remaining hour

Tags: php, datetime, time

i am implementing one application in which i have to display a time difference in total hour from end date to start date. suppose i have both start date and end date in timestamp.so how i will get the difference of date in total hour ?
now i am using the below code

```
 $intervalo = date_diff(date_create(), date_create($end));
    pr($intervalo);
```

and the output is like

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 1
    [d] => 4
    [h] => 18
    [i] => 41
    [s] => 2
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 34
)
```

the above code show me the total hour baut the end date is greater then 1month it shows 1m in array . but i only want total number of hour only
can any one help me  ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `date_diff`. Convert the dates to timestamps (which represent seconds), subtract the two, and divide by `3600`.

```
$x = date_create();
$y = date_create($end)
$hours = ($y->getTimestamp() - $x->getTimestamp()) / 3600;
```

If you want hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
$x = date_create();
$y = date_create($end)
$diff = ($y->getTimestamp() - $x->getTimestamp());

$seconds = $diff % 60;
$diff    = (int)($diff / 60);
$minutes = $diff % 60;
$diff    = (int)($diff / 60);
$hours   = $diff;
```

Comment: This is true for any situation where you need the difference in "clock time" (ie. hours, minutes, or seconds) -- as is the case in this question.  However, if you need calendar time (ie. days, months, or years), you *should* use `date_diff` in order to avoid being thrown off by irregularities like daylight savings time, and leap year.

Comment: thanks Alex Charron.. its working fine .. i want the remaining time in  (date minutes hour ) format.. i have total hour so how i will get data in that format

Comment: @deckjohn: Instead of putting it in a comment, I've updated the answer to include H:M:S.